# Get content within a html tag using php and replace it after processing

Tags: php, html, get

I have an html (sample.html) like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<!--content-->

<p>some content</p>

<!--content-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i get the content part that is between the 2 html comment `'<!--content-->'` using php? I want to get that, do some processing and place it back, so i have to get and put! Is it possible?

Comment: by "content" you mean `some content` or `<p>some content</p>` 
 and will the comment nodes always be written `<!--content-->`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

esafwan - you could use a regex expression to extract the content between the div (of a certain id).

I've done this for image tags before, so the same rules apply. i'll look out the code and update the message in a bit.

**[update]** try this:

```
<?php
    function get_tag( $attr, $value, $xml ) {

        $attr = preg_quote($attr);
        $value = preg_quote($value);

        $tag_regex = '/<div[^>]*'.$attr.'="'.$value.'">(.*?)<\\/div>/si';

        preg_match($tag_regex,
        $xml,
        $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    $yourentirehtml = file_get_contents("test.html");
    $extract = get_tag('id', 'content', $yourentirehtml);
    echo $extract;
?>
```

or more simply:

```
preg_match("/<div[^>]*id=\"content\">(.*?)<\\/div>/si", $text, $match);
$content = $match[1];
```

jim

Comment: so where is the `id` attribute in `<!--content-->`?

Comment: gordon - the section that's pulled out is the content that is contained within the content (id) div. along the same lines really as the jQuery $('#content').html() function

Comment: but how do i actually load the html to $yourentirehtml?

Comment: esafwan - if inside your php program and on the same domain, file_get_contents http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2FPHP%2Ffunc_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp&ei=TkNZTIPROqP20wTWhJHjCA&usg=AFQjCNFFmdhBH3AyMaQOkqXhAOHIGdauYQ&sig2=394azKvlwzBJCX6gXO2RPA if using javascript (or jquery) then the whole ball game changes. but i'm assuming you aren't as you haven't tagged the question as such.

Comment: @jim The OP asked for the content between the comment nodes. While pragmatically your solution is feasible, it it is technically not what was asked.

Comment: yes, sometimes the impedence between the question and the answer CAN balance out - :-) thanks...

Answer (score 9):

If this is a **simple** replacement that does not involve parsing of the actual HTML document, you may use a Regular Expression or even just `str_replace` for this. But generally, [it is not a advisable to use Regex for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) because HTML is not regular and [coming up with reliable patterns can quickly become a nightmare](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

The right way [to parse HTML in PHP](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0081_parse_html_extract_data_from_html.html) is to use a parsing library that actually knows how to make sense of HTML documents. Your best native bet would be [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) but PHP has a number of [other native XML extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) you can use and there is also a number of third party libraries like [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

If you use the [search function, you will see that this topic has been covered extensively](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+html+parse+php) and you should have no problems finding examples that show how to solve your question.

Comment: +1, and if you're looking for a proper XPath to match the nodes, it's `(//*|//text())[preceding-sibling::comment()='content' and following-sibling::comment()='content']`

Comment: Thanx... All the links helped me a lot, though it didn't answer me straight.. Links are worth reading and helped me gain more depth in php!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    $content=file_get_contents("sample.html");
    $comment=explode("<!--content-->",$content);
    $comment=explode("<!--content-->",$comment[1]);
    var_dump(strip_tags($comment[0]));
?>
```

check this ,it will work for you

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with nested divs
I found solution [here](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=102670#p551340)

```
<?php // File: MatchAllDivMain.php
// Read html file to be processed into $data variable
$data = file_get_contents('test.html');
// Commented regex to extract contents from <div class="main">contents</div>
//  where "contents" may contain nested <div>s.
//  Regex uses PCRE's recursive (?1) sub expression syntax to recurs group 1
$pattern_long = '{           # recursive regex to capture contents of "main" DIV
<div\s+class="main"\s*>              # match the "main" class DIV opening tag
  (                                   # capture "main" DIV contents into $1
    (?:                               # non-cap group for nesting * quantifier
      (?: (?!<div[^>]*>|</div>). )++  # possessively match all non-DIV tag chars
    |                                 # or 
      <div[^>]*>(?1)</div>            # recursively match nested <div>xyz</div>
    )*                                # loop however deep as necessary
  )                                   # end group 1 capture
</div>                               # match the "main" class DIV closing tag
}six';  // single-line (dot matches all), ignore case and free spacing modes ON

// short version of same regex
$pattern_short = '{<div\s+class="main"\s*>((?:(?:(?!<div[^>]*>|</div>).)++|<div[^>]*>(?    1)</div>)*)</div>}si';

$matchcount = preg_match_all($pattern_long, $data, $matches);
// $matchcount = preg_match_all($pattern_short, $data, $matches);
echo("<pre>\n");
if ($matchcount > 0) {
    echo("$matchcount matches found.\n");
//  print_r($matches);
    for($i = 0; $i < $matchcount; $i++) {
        echo("\nMatch #" . ($i + 1) . ":\n");
        echo($matches[1][$i]); // print 1st capture group for match number i
    }
} else {
    echo('No matches');
}
echo("\n</pre>");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here for a code example that means you can load a HTML document into SimpleXML  http://blog.charlvn.com/2009/03/html-in-php-simplexml.html

You can then treat it as a normal [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) object.

EDIT: This will only work if you want the content in a tag (e.g. between <div> and </div>)