# Replace property <a> tag

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get content within a html tag using php and replace it after processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404433/get-content-within-a-html-tag-using-php-and-replace-it-after-processing)

I want replace

```
<a href="#" alt="" title="" class=""....>blalablabla</a>
```

with: blalablabla

Comment: I've tried to format to capture the HTML, but I'm not sure it's really what you want. Please edit accordingly if this is not right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `strip_tags()` funciton

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Here is the example.

```
$sHTML = '<a href="#" alt="" title="" class=""....>blalablabla</a>';
$sStripped = strip_tags($sHTML);
echo $sStripped; // should echo "blalablabla"
```