# How to get content inside opening and closing elements with PHP DOM Document

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm learning about HTML parsing in PHP and I'm trying to use it to get the content in-between an opening and closing tag.

I've read the documentation and can't figure out how to do it.

I know how to get elements and get their attributes, but not what they contain.

How can I do that with Dom Document in PHP?

For example getting the contents inside the opening `<title>` and closing `</title>` ?

Comment: Please refer to this page. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404433/get-content-within-a-html-tag-using-php-and-replace-it-after-processing

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library, it's really helpful and easy to use.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/