# How to get perticular content from html tag attribute into php

Tags: php, html

i have following html content

```
<p>Hello World<p>
<img style="height:175px; width:312px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4Xu....">
<span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fringilla ipsum vitae fermentum accumsan. Nam pellentesque</span>
```

Now i want to get text `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU....` contain into `<img>` tag and from `src`.

How can i get this specific text from html.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you elaborate your requirement.

Comment: i want to get `src` data from <img> tag.

Comment: Parse html with some xml-parsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404433/get-content-within-a-html-tag-using-php-and-replace-it-after-processing  try this

Comment: Get your data using   `$("#img1").src.split(",")[1];` and then send it using whatever mechanism in the links above

Comment: @SatejS — That gives *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'*

Comment: Do that in Javascript!Also, give your image an id img1

Comment: @SatejS — The question is tagged **PHP** not JavaScript.

Comment: Correct, my method suggests sending the value from HTML to PHP via JS.That is, using JS to extract the exact data item required, and then sending it via POST/anything etc.

Comment: @SatejS — So rather than just parse the HTML with PHP, they should grab all of the HTML, modify it to add JavaScript, send it to a browser, get the browser to extract the data, then send it back to the PHP (presumably by making an HTTP request and triggering a second PHP script) … this sounds like a massively overcomplicated approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an `id` (`test`) to image element and with jquery you could fetch `src` attribute of image with below code.

**Jquery**

```
var srcImage = $("#test").attr("src");
```

**Or with Javascript**

```
var srcImage = document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("src");
```

Now you could perform `string` operation on `srcImage` if you want particular part of `src`

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/aq0a9jqs/

Sorry Jazz I did not notice that it was exclusively for php. 
Kindly refer to question tagged by Quentin as reference. It provides multiple options on how to load/parse html content in php.

There are multiple ways to parse html from string/file/url. Once parsing is performed you could fetch elements from parsed content with supported functions. After referring to answers in tagged question I found `SimpleHTMLDOMParser` easy to use.

You could you it as below for your problem in particular.

**Load HTML from file/URL**

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/'); //Your HTML url or file
```

**Find image with attribute id=test**

```
$ret = $html->find('img[id=test]'); //this will work if image element has ID if you can not change html then use foreach method mentioned in documentations.
```

**Get a attribute ( If the attribute is non-value attribute (eg. checked, selected...), it will returns true or false)**

```
$value = $ret->src;
```

This is what I understood by referring to documentations here. I have not tested it. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/  **and**
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

Give it a try and see how it works out. Also refer to other possibilities from tagged question and choose whichever is easy for you. I hope it helps you. lmk.

Comment: The question says **PHP**, not JavaScript

Comment: yes now it working , now if any one wants in php then convert it , don't  do down votes , he try to help atleast

Comment: @pratikwebdev thanks for your kind help this also helps me

Comment: @Jazz you are welcome. I updated answer with solution from my understanding of simplehtmlparser. Please try and check if it works for you. AmiteshKumar Thank you for consideration. I got to learn few things about php :)