# preg match text between tags excluding same tag in between

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, pcre

Well I know there several questions similar but could not find any with this specific case.

I took one code and tweak it to my needs but now I'm founding a bug on it that I can't correct.

Code:

```
$tag = 'namespace';
$match = Tags::get($f, $tag);
var_dump($match); 

  static function get( $xml, $tag) { // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404433/get-content-within-a-html-tag-using-7-processing
// bug case      string(56) "<namespaces>
//      <namespace key="-2">Media</namespace>"
      $tag_ini = "<{$tag}[^\>]*?>"; $tag_end = "<\\/{$tag}>";
      $tag_regex = '/' . $tag_ini . '(.*?)' . $tag_end . '/si';

      preg_match_all($tag_regex,
      $xml,
      $matches,
      PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
      return $matches;
  }
```

As you can see, there is a bug if the tag is nested:

> `<namespaces> <namespace key="-2">Media</namespace>`

When it should return 'Media', or even the outer `'<namespaces>'` and then the inside ones.

I tried to add "`<{$tag}[^\>|^\r\n ]*?>`", `^\s+`, changing the * to *?, and other few things that in best case turned to recognize only the bugged case.

Also tried `"<{$tag}[^{$tag}]*?>"` which gives blank, I suppose it nullifies itself.

I'm a newb on regex, I can tell that to fix this just is needed to add don't let open a new tag of the same type. 
Or I could even use a hack answer for my use case, that excludes if the inside text has new line carriage.

Can anyone get the right syntax for this?

---

You can check an extract of the text here: http://pastebin.com/f2naN2S3

---

After the proposed change:       `$tag_ini = "<{$tag}\\b[^>]*>"; $tag_end = "<\\/{$tag}>";` it does work for the the example case, but not for this one:

```
<namespace key="0" />
      <namespace key="1">Talk</namespace>
```

As it results in:

```
<namespace key="1">Talk"
```

It's because numbers and " and letters are considered inside word boundary. How could I address that?

Comment: Currently trying:       $tag_regex = '/' . $tag_ini . "[^{$tag_ini}]*?" . $tag_end . '/si';

Comment: If you downvote you could comment the reason why it is not a good question

Comment: But for a nice description and a snippet, a lot more downvotes could have been cast on the question as you try to manipulate XML with regex. As for why you get namespaces tag, you did not use a word boundary: `$tag_ini = "<{$tag}\\b[^>]*>";`. However, that would  not solve the issue of nested tags, you'd need a [recursive regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html). Still, you'd better use a DOM parse to just parse contents between tags.

Comment: I'm working with dumps of markdown that happen to have XML, not with html itself. I will try to learn about recursive regex, thanks for the tip

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you post as an answer I will accept it, as it lead to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you did not use a word boundary after the opening tag and thus, `namespace` in the pattern could also match `namespaces` tag, and many others.

The subsequent issue is that the `<${tag}\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/${tag}>` pattern would overfire if there is a self-closing `namespace` tag followed with a "normal" paired open/close `namespace` tag. So, you need to either use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\/)` before the `>` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY8gX4/1)), or use a `(?![^>]*\/>)` negative lookahead after `\b` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY8gX4/2)).

So, you can use

```
$tag_ini = "<{$tag}\\b[^>]*(?<!\\/)>"; $tag_end = "<\\/{$tag}>";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having hard time to understand. Regex seems like chinese for me :(
You mean that if there is <namespace key="0" />, the next <namespace></namespace> will be included in the previous one, like in the bug example?
But this is working the same as the others: https://regex101.com/r/iC2aN5/1 ?
I'm I missing something? could you set in the demo where mine fails and yours works so I can see the difference?
I appreciate your patience

Comment: Your regex does not allow ``\`` inside any of the tag contents. It does not match any text that is not `/>`. To match any text that is not `/>`, you need a tempered greedy token like `(?:(?!\/>).)*`. OR an unrolled one: `[^\/]*(?:\/(?!>)[^\/]*)*`

Comment: Too much regex complexity for me. Let us just solve the question for this use case if you agree, and once it's done I'll try to understand the why. If not, I'm so overwhelmed. 
If I simplify mine, to \\b[^>\/]*>, wouldn't that work? It seems to work indeed in my tests. So takes everything up to what is not > or /. Right ?

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY8gX4/3). Improper regex can be treacherous, and work in some cases, but in some situations, it will fail. You just should be aware when and with which contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the idea answer, but I was messing with a regex generator:

```
<?php
# URL that generated this code:
# http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=%3Cnamespace%3E%3Cnamespace%20key=%22-2%22%3EMedia%3C/namespace%3E&12&11

$txt='arstarstarstarstarstarst<namespace key="-2">Media</namespace>arstarstarstarstarst';

$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
$re3='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re4='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
$re5='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re6='(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'; # Uninteresting: word
$re7='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re8='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';   # Word 1

if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2.$re3.$re4.$re5.$re6.$re7.$re8."/is", $txt, $matches))
{
    $word1=$matches[1][0];
    print "($word1) \n";
}

#-----
# Paste the code into a new php file. Then in Unix:
# $ php x.php
#-----
?>
```

Comment: Now, that IS a very useful link. But I'm doing things with the output so I need something else. 
I think this won't work with a larger text where I substract a phrase, this case is parsing a document.

Comment: It would help if you posted more of the document.

Comment: I mean, any text with nested tags is suitable for the test

Comment: Sorry, I realized that link is in .zim format, I will try to find the raw one, but you get the point. Edit.: here a link in the same format as I work with, https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles2.xml-p000030304p000088444.bz2 Ok it's xml but most of the content that I work with does not use the tags, that's why I consider regex over DOM for this case

Answer (score 0):

This line is what I needed

```
   $tag_ini = "<{$tag}\\b[^>|^\\/>]*>"; $tag_end = "<\\/{$tag}>";
```

Thank you very much you @Alison and @Wictor for your help and directions

Comment: Character classes consider symbols inside as separate units, thus, your `[^>|^\\/>]` is not correct (it matches any character other than `>`, `|`, `^`, `/`.

Comment: I thought | is like an 'or' operator :x

Comment: `|` outside a character class is an alternation operator. Inside a character class, it is a literal pipe symbol.